# How to pair automatically bluetooth devices with a PIN

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying, without success, to pair a bluetooth device with a Android phone without asking to the user the PIN.

My idea is to fetch the desired PIN from a web service because the bluetooth device I want pair needs to be used from more people (and so for more android phones) without knowing and enter the PIN.

Do you have any idea for do it? I tried to see Bluetooth classes, but always, during device connection, I need to enter the PIN.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's no easy answer.  Do a google search for "android oob pairing" to see the relevant discussions.  OOB (out of band) pairing is normally done with NFC, but it can also apply to your case of using a web service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "just works" feature of Bluetooth pairing. This works only with SSP(secure simple pairing), from Bluetooth 2.1 onwards.
You have to set the IO capabilities of device for this to work.